# R: Slope to extract numbers from multiple variables of string data in a complex numeric/string-mixed dataset

Tags: r, string, numeric, substr, gsub

I have a 18 similar dataframes (each representing a survey year) from the German economic panel (SOEP) which is part string and part numeric. The variables (over 200 in each DF) have the following values

- first 4 are numeric identifiers of person and household
- some are numbers "-2" till "12"
- some are string Type 1 as "[1] Ja" or "[-2] Nein"
- some are string Type 2 as "[1] Jan Vollzeit erwerbst." or "[-2] trifft nicht zu"

I already tried a `sapply`-command but the I receive a matrix convertible to a data frame without the 4 Identifier-Variables and still have the brackets around my numbers (PKAL06 is my starting DF).

```
PKs <- sapply(PKAL06[5:225], function(PKAL06) substr (PKAL06,1,3)) 
PKsD <- data.frame(PKs)
```

As well I tried a combination with `gsub`, but it just gave me NA instead of strings.

```
PKas <- sapply(PKAL06, 
   function(PKAL06) as.numeric(gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", PKAL06)))
```

Ideally someone could give me a hint how to tell R to change the string variables of the whole(!) data frame into numeric variables by extracting, what is between the brackets. The output should be data frame of the same structure with all variables as before, not a matrix, not a list.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please consider posting some example data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I gather from the [SOEP website](http://www.diw.de/en/diw_02.c.222516.en/data.html) that the data is confidential, so try this:

```
PKas <- sapply(PKAL06, 
   function(PKAL06) as.numeric(gsub("\\[([0-9|\\-]+)\\].+","\\1", PKAL06)))
```

The pattern above seems to work with your example data.

```
str <- c("[1] Ja","[-2] Nein")
as.numeric(gsub("\\[([0-9|\\-]+)\\].+","\\1",str))
# [1]  1 -2

str <- c("[1] Jan Vollzeit erwerbst.","[-2] trifft nicht zu")
as.numeric(gsub("\\[([0-9|\\-]+)\\].+","\\1",str))
# [1]  1 -2
```

You (seem to...) want to extract whatever is between the brackets. But `[` is a special character in regular expression syntax, so you have to escape it using `\\[` or `\\]`. The code above goes a bit further in accepting only digits or `-` between brackets.

Comment: The "\\[" and "//]" were exactly what I needed and it solved my problem flawlessly.